# Fill matrix with random but different numbers

Tags: c#, matrix, random, numbers

I have to fill a matrix with randomic numbers from a set of (-1,0,1)...
My code do this, however I would like that my matrix has more different elements inside of it.
I try to explain myself better with an example.

One of the output of my code is:

```
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
1,1,0,0,1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1
0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,-1,0,1,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,0,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,-1,0,-1,0,1
0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,-1,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1
1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,1,-1,1,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,-1,-1,0,-1,1,-1
0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,-1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,-1,-1,0,1,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,1,0,1,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,-1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,-1,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,0,0,0,-1
1,-1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,-1,0,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,1,0,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1
0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,1,1
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,0,0,1,0,-1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1
1,1,1,0,1,1,-1,1,-1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-1,0,1,1,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,-1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,-1,0,0,0,1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,-1,0,0,0,1
0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1
0,-1,0,0,0,-1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1
```

So not a lot of the same rows like in my output.

But I don't have an idea how to do this... it is possible?

My code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int righe = 2432; //rows
    int colonne=31; //coloumns

    int[,] matrice = new int[righe, colonne]; 

    for(int i = 0; i<righe; i++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < colonne; y++)
        {
            System.Random random = new System.Random();

            int number = random.Next(0, 2); 
            int[] choices = new int[3] { -1, 0, 1 }; 
            matrice[i, y] = choices[number]; //insert the random value
            Console.WriteLine(matrice[i, y]); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `System.Random random = new System.Random();` line outside the `for` loops. The random number generator is initialized (aka "seeded") with system time and if you call `new Random()` very often (like in your example), the time doesn't change enough. So you get the same random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Place `System.Random random = new System.Random();` outside of the loops.

Comment: It's generally preferred to explain what's going on rather than just giving a recommendation, because we're trying to teach people things, not just fix an issue once and have it creep up again and again because they don't understand the underlying problem. See [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31368307/1711796) for an example.